# Laravel ORM relation return data as array instead of object

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-5.5

I was trying to get the relational model data like

```
{{$OrderInfo->CustomerInfo->Phone}}
```

but it's giving error like

> Trying to get property of non-object

While we can easily access the returned data like

```
{{$OrderInfo->CustomerInfo['Phone']}}
```

My work is temporarily working, but I was not satisfied. It should worked to access the data as an object. Because, I think that is right process to access the data. Please can anyone help me to come out from the problem.

Thanks so much in advance for your valuable time!

Order, Customer Model & My Controller Code given below

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\OrderInfo;
use App\CustomerInfo;
use Mail;

class AdminOrderController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {    
        $Orders = OrderInfo::orderBy('OrderDate', 'DESC')->get();    
        return view('admin.admin-order-list', [        
            'Orders' => $Orders,        
        ]);    

     }
}


namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;    
class OrderInfo extends Model
{        
    protected $table = 'order_info';
    public $timestamps = false;        
    protected $primaryKey = 'OrderId';        

    public function CustomerInfo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CustomerInfo', 'CustomerID');
    }        
}

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerInfo extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'customer_info';
    public $timestamps = false;    
    protected $primaryKey = 'CustomerID';    
    protected $fillable = ['CustomerID','Phone'];

    public function OrderInfo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderInfo', 'CustomerID');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass data to your view by `compact('Orders')` instead of passing array?!

Comment: Thanks for your help @SoheilRt. Does it matter. I had not tried that, let me check & will inform here.

Comment: I was not familiar with compact @soheil-rt. Although, I had passed the data to view file like `return view('admin.admin-order-list', [
        'user' => $user,
        'page_name' => 'Order List',        
        'OrderStatus'=>$OrderStatus
      ])->with(compact('Orders'));`

but still it not works same error  **Trying to get property of non-object**